# Bind Quill to asp net core model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, quill

I am using ASP.Net Core form to pass data from user to server with code:

```
@model SomeModel
@using(Html.BeginForm(...))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(s => s.PropertyName);
}
```

which works fine but now i have field which need to be populated from quill editor. Quill request me to pass him `div` container for his job and i do not know how to bind that container to my model property. I have tried giving that div `id` and `name` just as property name but it didn't work. Also tried adding `runat = server` but still not working.

Here is my full code:

```
@model ClanakModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "New story";
}

<style>
    #Naslov {
        width: 80%;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    #GrupaID {
        height: 30px;
        width: 18%;
        margin-left: 2%;
    }

    input {
        border: 1px solid gray;
        background-color: whitesmoke;
        padding: 5px;
        border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    }

    #Tekst {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
        min-width: 100%;
    }

    #Publish_btn {
        float: right;
        border: 2px solid black;
        background-color: white;
        margin-top: 20px;
        border-radius: 20px;
        padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
    }

    #Publish_btn:hover {
        background-color: deepskyblue;
    }
</style>

<h2>Write new story</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateNew", "Story", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.Naslov, new { @placeholder = "Title" });
    @Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.GrupaID, new SelectList(GrupaModel.List(), "GrupaID", "Naziv"));
    <div id="Tekst" name="Tekst"></div>

    <button id="Publish_btn">Publish</button>
}
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js"></script>
<script>
    var toolbarOptions = [
        ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],        // toggled buttons
        ['image'],
        ['blockquote', 'code-block'],

        [{ 'header': 1 }, { 'header': 2 }],               // custom button values
        [{ 'list': 'ordered' }, { 'list': 'bullet' }],
        [{ 'script': 'sub' }, { 'script': 'super' }],      // superscript/subscript
        [{ 'indent': '-1' }, { 'indent': '+1' }],          // outdent/indent
        [{ 'direction': 'rtl' }],                         // text direction

        [{ 'size': ['small', false, 'large', 'huge'] }],  // custom dropdown
        [{ 'header': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],

        [{ 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }],          // dropdown with defaults from theme
        [{ 'font': [] }],
        [{ 'align': [] }],

        ['clean']                                         // remove formatting button
    ];
    var options = {
        theme: 'snow',
        placeholder: 'Start writing here!',
        modules: {
            toolbar: toolbarOptions
        }
    };
    var quill = new Quill('#Tekst', options);
</script>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with 'runat = server' in Asp.NET Core

Answer (score 2):

Since DIVs are not input elements, you could add a `hidden` input which accepts the content of the editor when you submit the form.You could get Editor content in js using `quill.getContents()`.

Assuming that your model has a `Description` field, below is a simple demo:

```
@model SomeModel
<h2>Write new story</h2>

<form id="form" method="post">

    <input asp-for="Description" name="Description" type="hidden" class="form-control" />
    <div id="Tekst" name="Tekst"></div>

    <input type="submit" id="Publish_btn" value="Publish" />
</form>
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js"></script>
<script>
var toolbarOptions = [
    ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],        // toggled buttons
    ['image'],
    ['blockquote', 'code-block'],

    [{ 'header': 1 }, { 'header': 2 }],               // custom button values
    [{ 'list': 'ordered' }, { 'list': 'bullet' }],
    [{ 'script': 'sub' }, { 'script': 'super' }],      // superscript/subscript
    [{ 'indent': '-1' }, { 'indent': '+1' }],          // outdent/indent
    [{ 'direction': 'rtl' }],                         // text direction

    [{ 'size': ['small', false, 'large', 'huge'] }],  // custom dropdown
    [{ 'header': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],

    [{ 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }],          // dropdown with defaults from theme
    [{ 'font': [] }],
    [{ 'align': [] }],

    ['clean']                                         // remove formatting button
];
var options = {
    theme: 'snow',
    placeholder: 'Start writing here!',
    modules: {
        toolbar: toolbarOptions
    }
};
var quill = new Quill('#Tekst', options);

var form = document.querySelector('form');
form.onsubmit = function () {
    // Populate hidden form on submit
    var description = document.querySelector('input[name=Description]');
    description.value = quill.getContents();
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Quill content is described by the [Deltas format](https://quilljs.com/docs/delta/). This format is a subset of JSON, well suited for many applications. If you need to get raw HTML content, the simplest option from JavaScript would be:

```
var html = quill.root.innerHTML;
```

Assuming that your model has a `Comment` field, Your modified code would be:

```
@model ClanakModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "New story";
}
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js"></script>

<h2>Write new story</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateNew", "Story", FormMethod.Post, new { id="form", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.Naslov, new { placeholder = "Title" });
    @Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.GrupaID, new SelectList(GrupaModel.List(), "GrupaID", "Naziv"));

    <!-- Hidden input to accept the contents of Quill -->
    @Html.HiddenFor(c => c.Comment, new { @class = "form-control" })

    <!-- Quill editor -->
    <div class="form-control">
        <div class="comment-toolbar">
            <span class="ql-formats">
                <button class="ql-bold"></button>
                <button class="ql-italic"></button>
                <button class="ql-underline"></button>
                <button class="ql-strike"></button>
                <button class="ql-list" value="ordered"></button>
                <button class="ql-list" value="bullet"></button>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="comment-editor">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /Quill editor -->

    <button type="submit" id="Publish_btn">Publish</button>
}

<script>
    var commentEditor = document.querySelector('.comment-editor');

    if (commentEditor) {
        var quill = new Quill(commentEditor, {
            modules: {
                toolbar: '.comment-toolbar'
            },
            placeholder: 'Leave a comment',
            theme: 'snow'
        });

        quill.on('text-change', function (delta, source) {
            updateComment();
        })

        // You will get the raw HTML without Quill classes.
        function getQuillHtml() { return quill.root.innerHTML; }

        function updateComment() {
            let html = getQuillHtml();
            // Copy HTML content into hidden input
            document.querySelector('#Comment').value = html;
        }
    }
</script>
```

This will copy the HTML content when you modify the content in the editor. If you need to post the HTML content, you can copy the HTML content inside Quill editor when the submit button is clicked. To do so, include the following in the `script` section:

```
    var form = document.querySelector('#form');
    form.onsubmit = function () {
        updateComment();
    };
```

However, if you store the content in a database, I recommend to store in the [Deltas format](https://quilljs.com/docs/delta/) to keep compatibility with the Quill editor.